# Where can I find a historical copy of an application?

Tags: patent-applications

In reference to the patent: [US20050025364](https://www.google.com/patents/US20050025364)

I used this patent application as a reference in my thesis report but now it is having different content. Where can I find the content that I saw before?

Answer (score 0):

If you go to the page on Google Patents, click the "Espacenet" link, then click on the "Global Dossier" link in Espacenet, you would see a history of the application, including original application and amendments.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the USPTO Public PAIR (patent application information retrieval) system at http://portal.uspto.gov/pair/PublicPair and enter the application number or the publication number.   You will be able to download the application as originally filed, along with any amendments to the application and complete history of the prosecution of the application.

Answer (score -1):

> I used this patent as a reference in my thesis report but now it is having different content.

Unlikely. Maybe you didn't scroll down enough? It says, for example:

> Assuming that the life line has a 170-pixel length and a 36° slope, the head line has a 150-pixel length and a 1.820° slope, and the heart line has a 160-pixel length, the control section 110 obtains such data at step 1300 and proceeds to display the following results of palm reading on the display section 160:
>
> [Health] bla bla bla
>
> [Intellect] bla bla bla
>
> [Character] bla bla bla
>
> [Love] bla bla bla

Er, good luck with your report ...

Comment: When you say "unlikely", you mean "unlikely what"?

Comment: @Pacerier he means that content donot change in same published patent application if it changes it goes with certificate of correction.

Comment: Patent applications are amended during their prosecution. The history is now at PatentCenter since Public pair is gone. The certificate of correction is for issued patents, not applications.